# Clipboard Copy and Paste does not work in VMWare Player 12

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, clipboard, copy-paste, vmware-player

i can copy and paste text and files between Virtuelle Maschine (Windows 7) and my local Windows 7. But I can't copy this what is in clipboard - for example between two displays the same program (on display in Virtuale Maschine and second display in local Windows).

I have no option: VM > Options tab > Guest Isolation > Enable the Copy and paste

[image]

In VMWare Workstation it's worked but not in VMWare Player.
How to fix it ?

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: 
This is my routine now to fix it:

## VM:

`$ apt-get autoremove open-vm-tools
$ apt-get install open-vm-tools
$ apt --fix-broken install`

Close VM.

## In Windows Host:

`echo off | clip`

Start VM.

Hopefully works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

As of Aug'2023:

#### Install the right package:

- [VMWare recommends](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1022525) using "open-vm-tools" instead of "VMWare Tools" on Ubuntu.
- `open-vm-tools-desktop` is [the package that provides](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Tools/12.2.0/com.vmware.vsphere.vmwaretools.doc/GUID-8B6EA5B7-453B-48AA-92E5-DB7F061341D1.html) drag-n-drop/clipboard sharing functionality.

So `sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools-desktop` is what you need.

`open-vm-tools` is also needed, but it is a dependency of `open-vm-tools-desktop` so gets installed implicitly.

---

#### Start/restart the right daemon (`vmtoolsd`):

In my case I had two instances of `vmtoolsd` running.

```bash
$ ps -eaf | grep vmtoolsd
  UID   PID  PPID   C STIME   TTY           TIME CMD
root       15281       1  0 Aug10 ?        00:03:58 /usr/bin/vmtoolsd
kash       15545     978  0 Aug10 ?        00:03:44 /usr/bin/vmtoolsd -n vmusr --blockFd 3 --uinputFd 4
$
```

- `sudo systemctl restart open-vm-tools` (or `sudo service open-vm-tools restart`) restarts the first daemon (running as `root`). This does nothing (copy paste still doesn't work).
- What worked was to restart the "user" process. In my case the one running as `kash`:

```bash
$ my_uid=`id -u`
$ kill -9 $(ps -u $my_uid | grep vmtoolsd | awk '{print $1}')
$ /usr/bin/vmtoolsd -n vmusr --blockFd 3 --uinputFd 4 -b /var/run/user/$my_uid/vmtoolsd.pid
```

Values of fds taken from the original process that was killed.

---

My env:

```
$ lsb_release --all
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
$
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have VMware Workstation Pro make sure you don't have it disabled in the settings:
`VM > Options tab > Guest Isolation > Enable the Copy and paste`

Comment: The same information I founded in Google. But unfortunately I don't have options "Guest Isolation". Maybe Guest Isolation ist in wmware Workstation but not in Player ?

Comment: I addes screenshot, can you schow me where is the option ?

Comment: "Guest Isolation" is only available with Workstation Pro